# Macports LLVM-3.9 installation

Tags: terminal, llvm, macos-sierra, llvm-clang

I'm trying to install clang and llvm as they are dependencies of PySide2. Using macports, I have installed llvm and clang and port installed indicates they are active.

```
The following ports are currently installed:
  bzip2 @1.0.6_0 (active)
  cctools @895_4+llvm39 (active)
  clang-4.0 @4.0.0_0+analyzer+libstdcxx (active)
  clang_select @2_0 (active)
  db48 @4.8.30_4 (active)
  expat @2.2.1_1 (active)
  gcc6 @6.3.0_2 (active)
  gcc_select @0.1_8 (active)
  gdbm @1.13_3 (active)
  gettext @0.19.8.1_0 (active)
  gmp @6.1.2_0 (active)
  isl @0.18_0 (active)
  ld64 @3_0 (active)
  ld64-latest @274.2_1+llvm39 (active)
  libcxx @3.9.1_0+universal (active)
  libedit @20170329-3.1_0 (active)
  libffi @3.2.1_0 (active)
  libgcc @6.3.0_0 (active)
  libiconv @1.15_0 (active)
  libmpc @1.0.3_0 (active)
  libomp @3.9.1_0+universal (active)
  libxml2 @2.9.4_1 (active)
  llvm-3.9 @3.9.1_3 (active)
  llvm-4.0 @4.0.0_0 (active)
  llvm_select @2_0 (active)
  mpfr @3.1.5_0 (active)
  ncurses @6.0-20170610_0 (active)
  openssl @1.0.2l_0 (active)
  perl5 @5.24.1_0+perl5_24 (active)
  perl5.24 @5.24.1_0 (active)
  python2_select @0.0_2 (active)
  python27 @2.7.13_1 (active)
  python_select @0.3_7 (active)
  readline @7.0.003_1 (active)
  sqlite3 @3.19.3_0 (active)
  xar @1.5.2_2 (active)
  xz @5.2.3_0 (active)
  zlib @1.2.11_0 (active)
```

However, I cannot run llvm-config from the command line, so is llvm actually installed? Or is there a problem with linking?

Comment: Did you check your path exports? I used "Homebrew" to install LLVM 4.0 this morning and llvm-config runs fine after I added path to binaries.

Comment: You were right, I fixed it by changing adding the path to my .bash_profile. Still haven't gotten through installing PySide2, but I can at least close this issue.

Comment: Yeah, **Ockham's Razor** is a strategy that should be in the thought tool-belt. It's the simple things that often confound us and get hidden by thoughts of much more elaborate issues.